# how HTTPS request is handled by IIS server

Tags: sql, apache, http, iis-7

I am trying to understand the working of HTTP , IIS and sql server.

I am having an *IIS 7 server* in my environment which is interacting with a *sql database server*.

The architecture is

`Apache ----> IIS -----> SQL server`

The Apache is a reverse proxy server which is sending the HTTP request to the IIS server and from there IIS server is interacting with the  SQL database connecting by different application pools for different applications.

My query is if some request has been forwarded by the Apache server and it has reached the IIS ; after that, if the network between the Apache and IIS is having any packet drops ;

- **Will that have any affect to the performance of IIS and database server?**
- **Will there be any long running queries in the worker process of the IIS?** Because my concern is what will happen after the queries that has successfully executed in the Database server. But since the network between the IIS and Apache is broken how can they be forwarded further to the Apache and further to the end user.
- **Will these queries keep on holding the resources till they are forwarded from IIS to Apache?** Because they have successfully completed their tasks but because of network issue they are not being forwarded further. Or are such request stacked up somewhere by the IIS to free up the resources for the upcoming requests??

Answer (score 0):

Once a request has reached IIS it will go and do the required actions, and format the reply. It will try to send the reply to the requestor but if the link has gone, it will be unable to. It will then abandon the request. Resources it is holding for that request will be freed.

To get the data it had for you, Apache has to repeat the request.

Comment: Ya that was my understanding also but i am still a bit confused here.
Lets say the IIS has got the result on the connection it has formed on with the sql server. 
But if the connection between the IIS and the Apache is broken; so till what time this request will be there in the IIS because it has been orphaned now.Is there any time out setting in the IIS for this that if it is not able to connect to the Apache in that specified time then;will it drop and free the resources.

Comment: My understanding is that it's pretty quick. In fact, IIS may not know that Apache has lost the connection: it could be that it just sends the response out over TCP and nothing is listening for it any more so it just gets lost - this will depend on exactly how the TCPIP socket handling is implemented. However its done, it will be fast.